# Is static class code secure/thread-safe when accessed from a Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, thread-safety

I appreciate that this type of question has been asked to death, but the more I read on SO the more confused I'm getting, so would appreciate a yes/no answer and respective explanation based around the following code.  I've tested the code and it works, but I'm seeking a little shared wisdom because I cannot simulate simultaneous access requests.

In my web application, the database has user accounts from multiple organisations.  The goal of the code is to retrieve some access credentials specific to their *respective organisation*, and then integrate with a 3rd party system using an object created using those credentials.

Is there any possibility below that a user may be exposed to the credentials of another organisation if multiple people hit this simultaneously, particularly:

1. Is the thread-safety of the page compromised when accessing the static code?
2. Can static code return a value to the incorrect thread when used as in my example?

### App-Wide Class Logic

```
public static class ThirdParty
{

    public class ThirdPartyCredentials
    {
        public string AppId { get; set; }
        public string AppSecret { get; set; }
    }

    // Retrieves the third-party system credentials for the current user's organisation
    public static ThirdPartyCredentials GetThirdPartyCloudCredentials()
    {
        ThirdPartyCredentials cc = new ThirdPartyCredentials();

        // This usually happens in business logic, but example shown here to illustrate UserId/OrganisationId come from user-based OWIN/Katana cookies
        var user = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(user.FindFirst("UserId").Value));
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrganisationId", SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(user.FindFirst("OrganisationId").Value));
        // Code removed from brevity, but returns a DataTable object containing the credentials
        using (DataTable dt = ....)
        {
            cc.AppId = dt.Rows[0]["ThirdPartyAppId"].ToString();
            cc.AppSecret = dt.Rows[0]["ThirdPartyAppSecret"].ToString();
            return cc;
        }
    }

    public static ApiClient GetApiClient()
    {
        var creds = GetThirdPartyCloudCredentials();

        return new ApiClient()
        {
            Username = creds.AppId,
            Password = creds.AppSecret
        };
    }
}
```

## Page Logic

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var apiClient = GetApiClient();
        var dataApi = new ThirdPartySystem.DataApi() {
            ApiClient = apiClient;
        };

        foreach (var c in dataApi.GetData().ObjectCollection)
        {
            MyDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(c.Title, c.Id));
        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems like you have only read access here so **where is the problem?**

Comment: HttpContext.Current is tied to the current thread, thus is a thread static object. As long as you don't spawn off a new thread to call GetThirdPartyCloudCredentials, you should be fine. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @AotN.  Yes, thank you for the explanation.  I wasn't sure about any *gotcha's* that might exist beyond what you're saying, hence the reach out for input & experience

Comment: Question updated based on close vote.